How do I extract an Audio from a video in Node.js?
I have a transcribing API route I made using Next.js API route. In that project I pass in an Audio file in the request. But now I wanted to pass in a video and extract the audio from it.
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { SpeechClient } from '@google-cloud/speech';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

// Decode the Base64 string from the environment variable
const base64EncodedCredentials = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_BASE64;
if (!base64EncodedCredentials) {
  throw new Error('Google Cloud service account credentials are not provided');
}

const credentialsBuffer = Buffer.from(base64EncodedCredentials, 'base64');
const credentials = JSON.parse(credentialsBuffer.toString('utf8'));

// Initialize the Google Cloud Speech client with the decoded credentials
const client = new SpeechClient({
  credentials: {
    client_email: credentials.client_email,
    private_key: credentials.private_key,
  },
  projectId: credentials.project_id,
});

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const formData = await req.formData();
    const file = formData.get('file') as File | null;

    if (!file) {
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'No audio file provided' }), { status: 400 });
    }

    const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const audioBytes = Buffer.from(bytes).toString('base64');

    const [response] = await client.recognize({
      audio: {
        content: audioBytes,
      },
      config: {
        encoding: 'MP3', // Use MP3 encoding if the file is MP3
        sampleRateHertz: 16000, // Adjust according to your audio file's sample rate
        languageCode: 'en-US', // Set the language code for Amharic
        model: 'default',
        useEnhanced: true,
        speechContexts: [
          {
            phrases: ['google cloud'],
            boost: 20.0,
          },
        ],
        enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
      },
    });

    if (!response.results || response.results.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('No transcription result');
    }

    // Extract transcription and word-level timestamps
    const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => {
        if (!result.alternatives || result.alternatives.length === 0) {
          return '';
        }
        return result.alternatives[0].transcript;
      })
      .join('\n');



    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ transcription}), { status: 200 });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('[ERROR_TRANSCRIBING]', error);
    return new NextResponse('Internal Error', { status: 500 });
  }
}

I don't want to use an API or even a cloud storage for storing the files. I just want to extract the audio from video and transcribe. How can I achieve this?

Hi @Mohammed Bekele, Have a look at this documentation, let me know if this helped you or not.

@DhirajSingh i think it suggested ffmpeg. but to do that i need to install it in my local machine. also when i deploy it there is a whole lot of process that doesn't even work. is there a perfect solution to this? ot even an api?

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
